Implementing cNFT (Bubblegum) Fractionalization
Background
I'm working on implementing a fractionalization mechanism for compressed NFTs (cNFTs) using the Bubblegum standard on Solana. The goal is to allow users to:

Lock their compressed NFT in a program
Receive fungible SPL tokens representing fractional ownership
Trade these fraction tokens freely

Technical Requirements

Input: Compressed NFT (Bubblegum standard)
Output: Multiple fungible SPL tokens
Need to handle Merkle proofs for the compressed NFT
Must maintain proper ownership tracking

Current Research
I've investigated:

Cardinal Protocol's token management systems
Metaplex's documentation on compressed NFTs
Traditional NFT fractionalization implementations

Specific Questions

Are there any existing open-source implementations that handle fractionalization specifically for compressed NFTs?
If not, what would be the recommended architecture pattern for:

Storing the compressed NFT's Merkle proof in the vault
Managing ownership verification for compressed assets
Handling the relationship between the locked cNFT and generated SPL tokens



Attempts
I understand the basic concept would involve:
// Pseudocode structure
pub struct FractionVault {
    tree_authority: Pubkey,
    leaf_owner: Pubkey,
    merkle_proof: Vec,
    fraction_mint: Pubkey,
    // ... additional fields
}

But I'm specifically looking for guidance on proper integration with the Bubblegum standard and handling of compressed NFT-specific requirements.
